# XCode Project Dependency Issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I currently have two static library projects (Core and Logging) and one App project in my XCode 4.6.1 Workspace.  The App project can properly reference the two Static library projects; however, I cannot add a Target Dependency between static library projects.

For instance, this is the dependency I would like to setup:

```
App  ->  Core
     ->  Logging

Core ->  Logging
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
Workspace
   Core
   App
   Logging
```

I'm not sure why I cannot add a Target Dependency between Core and Logging (the option to add the library does not show up for Logging in Core).  Maybe I should upgrade to 5.0 now?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind all.  I figured it out.  I needed to Link Binary with Libraries for the Static Library project... not add a Target Dependency.